# How to deal with a List of Objects after a Hibernate query against a single entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

After calling list() on a Hibernate Query which you expect to just return a list of Foo objects (see example below), how best would you deal with this situation?

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Foo");
List list = query.list();
```

I don't particularly like seeing this:

```
public List read() { ... }
```

When I would much prefer:

```
public List<Foo> read() { ... }
```

Would you expect callers of the read method to have cast to Foo for each element?  Is there a nice way to get the read method to return List< Foo >?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would you expect callers of the read method to have cast to Foo for each element? Is there a nice way to get the read method to return List< Foo >?

No, I wouldn't expect the caller to do the cast, so I'd write things like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Foo");
List<Foo> list = query.list();
```

And if you want to remove the non type-safe cast warning (the Hibernate Query API is not type-safe):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Foo");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Foo> list = query.list();
```